# NHibernate.MappingException when imported into Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a project  that implements NHibernate, the project works fine on my machine w/ Visual Studio 2010. When I import that project into Visual Studio 2012 I run into the  **NHibernate.MappingException** .

The .hbm.xml are set as an embedded resource and copy to output directory is set as copy always for all the .hbm.xml files.

**The project runs under VS 2010, so Im not sure how it could be mapping issue.**

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSqlCeDialect</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlServerCeDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=FirstSample.sdf</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="HibernateExample" namespace="HibernateExample.Domain" >
  <class name="Grains" table="Products">
    <id name="Id" type="integer">
      <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="Name" type="string"/>
    <property name="Category" type="string"/>
    <property name="Discontinued" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="HibernateExample" namespace="HibernateExample.Domain" >
  <class name="Dairy" table="Products">
    <id name="Id" type="integer">
      <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="Name" type="string"/>
    <property name="Category" type="string"/>
    <property name="Discontinued" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

### app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="hibernate-configuration" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate" />
  </configSections>
  <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2" >
    <session-factory>
      <property name="connection.driver_class"> NHibernate.Driver.SqlServerCeDriver</property>
        <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSqlCeDialect</property>
      <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=FirstSample.sdf;</property>
      <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>


  <connectionStrings>
        <add name="testconnectionstring"
            connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\FirstSample.sdf;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client.3.5" />
    </connectionStrings>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urnchemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data.SqlServerCe" publicKeyToken="89845DCD8080CC91" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.242.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>

  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

---

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

A first chance exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in NHibernate.dll

A first chance exception of type 'NHibernate.MappingException' occurred in NHibernate.dll

A first chance exception of type 'NHibernate.MappingException' occurred in NHibernate.dll

A first chance exception of type 'NHibernate.MappingException' occurred in NHibernate.dll

A first chance exception of type 'NHibernate.MappingException' occurred in NHibernate.dll

Error: NHibernate.MappingException: Could not compile the mapping document: HibernateExample.Domain.Dairy.hbm.xml ---> NHibernate.MappingException: persistent class HibernateExample.Domain.Dairy, HibernateExample not found ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'HibernateExample.Domain.Dairy' from assembly 'HibernateExample, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, ObjectHandleOnStack type)

at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)

at NHibernate.Util.ReflectHelper.TypeFromAssembly(AssemblyQualifiedTypeName name, Boolean throwOnError) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Util\ReflectHelper.cs:line 308

at NHibernate.Util.ReflectHelper.ClassForName(String name) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Util\ReflectHelper.cs:line 181

at NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.Binder.ClassForFullNameChecked(String fullName, String errorMessage) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Cfg\XmlHbmBinding\Binder.cs:line 99

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

at NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.Binder.ClassForFullNameChecked(String fullName, String errorMessage) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Cfg\XmlHbmBinding\Binder.cs:line 105

at NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.Binder.ClassForNameChecked(String name, Mappings mappings, String errorMessage) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Cfg\XmlHbmBinding\Binder.cs:line 117

at NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.ClassBinder.BindClass(IEntityMapping classMapping, PersistentClass model, IDictionary`2 inheritedMetas) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Cfg\XmlHbmBinding\ClassBinder.cs:line 32

at NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.RootClassBinder.Bind(HbmClass classSchema, IDictionary`2 inheritedMetas) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Cfg\XmlHbmBinding\RootClassBinder.cs:line 21

at NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.MappingRootBinder.AddRootClasses(HbmClass rootClass, IDictionary`2 inheritedMetas) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Cfg\XmlHbmBinding\MappingRootBinder.cs:line 84

at NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.MappingRootBinder.AddEntitiesMappings(HbmMapping mappingSchema, IDictionary`2 inheritedMetas) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Cfg\XmlHbmBinding\MappingRootBinder.cs:line 42

at NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.MappingRootBinder.Bind(HbmMapping mappingSchema) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Cfg\XmlHbmBinding\MappingRootBinder.cs:line 31

at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddDeserializedMapping(HbmMapping mappingDocument, String documentFileName) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Cfg\Configuration.cs:line 523

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.LogAndThrow(Exception exception) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Cfg\Configuration.cs:line 342

at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddDeserializedMapping(HbmMapping mappingDocument, String documentFileName) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Cfg\Configuration.cs:line 530

at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddValidatedDocument(NamedXmlDocument doc) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Cfg\Configuration.cs:line 500

at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.ProcessMappingsQueue() in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Cfg\Configuration.cs:line 1865

at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddDocumentThroughQueue(NamedXmlDocument document) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Cfg\Configuration.cs:line 1857

at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddXmlReader(XmlReader hbmReader, String name) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Cfg\Configuration.cs:line 1850

at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddInputStream(Stream xmlInputStream, String name) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Cfg\Configuration.cs:line 652

at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddResource(String path, Assembly assembly) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Cfg\Configuration.cs:line 690

at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddAssembly(Assembly assembly) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Cfg\Configuration.cs:line 769

at HibernateExample.NHibernateTest.NHibernateHelper.OpenSession() in c:\Users\Fabian\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\NHibernate\HibernateExample\NHibernateTest\NHibernateHelper.cs:line 31

Error: Could not compile the mapping document: HibernateExample.Domain.Dairy.hbm.xml

A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in HibernateExample.exe
```

Comment: What does the mapping exception say?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, I added the stacktrace above in a new edit.

Comment: Is your `Dairy` class defined in the `NHibernateExample.Domain` namespace?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead , the assembly is HibernateExample so it is defined in the HibernateExample.Domain namespace.

Comment: If the mapping documents are embedded as resources, they should typically not also be copied to the output directory.

Comment: @OskarBerggren , I also set the property "copy always"  to output directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner exception with the all needed information is here:

> Error: NHibernate.MappingException: Could not compile the mapping
>   document: HibernateExample.Domain.Dairy.hbm.xml --->
>   NHibernate.MappingException: persistent class
>   HibernateExample.Domain.Dairy, HibernateExample not found --->
>   System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'HibernateExample.Domain.Dairy' from assembly 'HibernateExample,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

During the Factory configuration, NHibernate read all the embeded resources, including the third (from the top in your question):

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" 
  assembly="HibernateExample" 
  namespace="HibernateExample.Domain" >
  <class name="Dairy" table="Products">
```

So, the issue is clear. There is no `HibernateExample.Domain.Dairy` class available (not deployed, typo or incorrect namespace). *The good news or message is that your mapping was found and parsed...*

Try to assure, that the application has access to classes which are mapped

Comment: I've checked and double checked the namespaces, why would it work in VS 2010 and not VS 2012 w/ no changes made to the code at all?

Comment: It looks like you're missing references.

Comment: The exception is pretty straightforward: what is mapped, cannot be found (by reflection). *`persistent class HibernateExample.Domain.Dairy, HibernateExample not found`* means, that inside the app domain (usually dll in a *bin*) is no such a class

Comment: As Phill suggested, the missing reference could be the reason for the "deployment" skip. So what we need *(is not the reference itself)*, but that the "POCO entity" assembly is really deployed, and available in app domain